# Entity Framework 6 using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy with Amazon EC2

Tags: .net, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, azure-sql-database

Is there any point of using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy when SQL Server 2012 is hosted on Amazon EC2?
The exceptions that SQL Azure is throwing are they unique (compare to regular SQL Server 2012) so that SqlAzureExecutionStrategy is only tuned to catch those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SqlAzureExecutionStrategy`](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.cs) is ultimately backed by [`SqlAzureRetriableExceptionDetector`](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlAzureRetriableExceptionDetector.cs).  Most likely the connection errors you have will be different than what [`SqlAzureRetriableExceptionDetector`](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlAzureRetriableExceptionDetector.cs) is looking for.  However, its easy to determine what errors are occuring by leveraging the new [logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464) abilities for EF6.  Then you can roll-your-own ExceptionDetector and retry as needed.

Here's a great [post](http://ritzlgrmft.blogspot.com/2014/03/working-with-sqlazureexecutionstrategy.html) walking through this entire process.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the errors are common with regular SQL Server, some are specific to SQL Azure (such as some of the throttling errors).